# Custom Base32 encoding code C#

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding

I am have written the following code below to encode a bitarray into custom base32 encoding string. My idea is user can mix the order of base32 array as per requirement and can add similar looking characters like I and 1 etc.

My intention of asking the question is: Is the code written in an appropriate manner or it lacks some basics. As far as i know it is generating the output as per the requirment, however i want to just validate the code here. If there are flaws do let me know.

A user will have a string which needs to be base32 encoded. So in his function he would call it this way.

```
BitArray ba = new BitArray(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(CustomString));
GenerateBase32FromString(ba);
```

Now the GenerateBase32FromString is as below

```
static string GenerateStringFromKey(BitArray ba)
{
    try
    {
        // user will modify the order as per requirement.
        char[] cProdKeyPoss = "ABGCD1EF2HI3KL4MN5PQ6RS7TV8WX9YZ".ToCharArray();
        StringBuilder finalstring = new StringBuilder();
        // add zero value bits to round off to multiple of 5
        //ba.Length = ba.Length + (5-(ba.Length % 5));
        // remove bits to round off to multiple of 5
        ba.Length = ba.Length - (ba.Length % 5);
        Console.WriteLine("ba.length = " + ba.Length.ToString());

        for (int i = 0; i < ba.Length; i = i + 5)
        {
            int[] bitvalue = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

            if (ba.Get(i) == true)
                bitvalue[0] = 1;

            if (ba.Get(i + 1) == true)
                bitvalue[1] = 1;

            if (ba.Get(i + 2) == true)
                bitvalue[2] = 1;

            if (ba.Get(i + 3) == true)
                bitvalue[3] = 1;

            if (ba.Get(i + 4) == true)
                bitvalue[4] = 1;

            int temp = (16 * bitvalue[0]) + (8 * bitvalue[1]) + (4 * bitvalue[2]) + (2 * bitvalue[3]) + (bitvalue[4]);
            finalstring.Append(cProdKeyPoss[temp].ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine(finalstring.ToString());
        return finalstring.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have kept both the options where i will chop the bits to round of to multiple of 5 or will add additional zero value bits to make it multiple of 5.

Comment: Frustrating to find a Base32 in C# just to find out there is no decode. To make sure your code works you would need to add a decode, so that e.g. decode32(encode32("123"))=="123"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few suggestions:

- You don't have any idea of "padding" - so you can't
- Pass the key characters in as a parameter to the method. You can have an overload for a "default" one if you want
- Either give the StringBuilder a capacity to start with, or create a char array of the right length and create the string directly from that
- Catching `Exception` is almost always a bad idea, and it certainly is here. Any exception would be due to a bug in this code, so just let it bubble up the stack
- Comparisons with "true" always look smelly to me, and I personally put if/for/while/etc statement bodies in blocks even for single statements, so I would have

  ```
  if (ba.Get(i))
  {
      bitValue[0] = 1;
  }
  ```
- There's no real point in having the bit array to start with. Why not just add to a value which starts at 0?

  ```
  if (ba.Get(i))
  {
      temp += 16;
  }
  // etc
  ```
- Repeated code like that suggests a loop:

  ```
  int temp = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
  {
      if (ba.Get(i + j))
      {
          // This could just be "1 << j" if you don't mind the
          // results being different to your current code
          temp += 1 << (4 - j);
      }
  }
  ```
- Library methods shouldn't write to the console
- Don't call `ToString` when you've got the right character - just call `Append(char)` (or set the value in the result char array).

Comment: Thanks Jon for valuable comments. The loop logic really shortened my code. You first comment indicated about padding. Since i would not be aware what length would be the string in terms of bits be i thought the approach of either adding or chopping off the bits should be there. Though i can add an argument asking use to decide either of the two options. Writing to console was just to check the output since was using console app for testing.

Comment: Also if you could explain why having an exception in the code is wrong. What i am trying to do here is, if things work normally then it would return the string in base-32 format. If incase there is some problem and exception is raised, i would return a null string and can add a messagebox showing the exception details. Would it be wrong approach?

Comment: @Kavitesh: The point is that at the point of encoding you *do* know the length of the string - so you can use padding to make sure you always end up with a round number of characters. Look at how base64 uses padding as an example. As for the exception: this is a relatively low level routine. It shouldn't make the decision about how an exception is handled. That's up to the calling application - which almost certainly shouldn't just catch "Exception" either, except at the topmost level. Usually anything low down the stack should only catch specific exceptions it can genuinely *handle*.